# How do i use re.search in a function?

Tags: python

I'm using a python in ubuntu command line and this is my code:

```
import re
from sys import stdin

def find(pat,text):
    m= re.match(pat,text)
    if m:
        print m.groups()
    else:
        print m.groups()

pat=stdin.readline()
text=stdin.readline()
answer= find(pat,text)
```

thats all... the error I get is :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: In `else` block, why you are doing `m.groups()` when you already know that the value of `m` is `None`?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's beacause of your else statement, if re.match fails he give you  a None objects.

you can use

```
m.groups()
```

only if you match

for example

```
str1 = "toto is happy"
print re.match("toto",str1).group()
```

will output

> 'toto'

but

```
str1 = "toto is happy"
print re.match("test",str1).group()
```

will fail and display your error

Comment: yes , when im using command line, the senario will not fail.. so it should match..my input is find(a,abc) so it should match